# How to add a UIImageView to a UIView (not a UIViewController)?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiimageview

I created view-based application.
I have got a sampleGameViewContrioller.xib, which contains main View, and child View, which connected with class Behavior.

SampleViewController.xib:

- View

  - View <- Behavior

In sampleViewContoller.m I create instance of the class Behavior:

```
Behavior *b = [[Behavior alloc] initilizeWithType:@"type" position:rect mapArray:arrMap];
```

Behavior.m:

```
 -(id) initilizeWithType:(NSString *)type position:(CGRect) pos mapArray:(NSMutableArray *) mapArr {

 self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 570)];
 if (self != nil) {
 if ([type isEqualToString:@"type"]) {
 arrMap = mapArr;
 self.rectForDraw = pos;
 self.file = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"girl.png"];
 UIImageView *imgg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl.png"]];
 imgg.frame = rect;
 [self addSubview:imgg];
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self selector:@selector(moving:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
 }
 return self;}
```

But it doesn't work. Image doesn't add to my View.

if I add imageView in -(void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect, it's working:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl.png"]];
 self.img.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
 [self addSubview:self.img]; }
```

But i should send parameters of drawing in class Behavior through constructor. How to add imageView without method drawRect, with my constructor?

sorry for my English :)

Comment: Can you clarify the following: What do you do with `b` after you have created it in your viewcontroller? Which `drawRect` are you overriding in your last code snippet? Is this the `Behavior` class?

Comment: i create an instance of classes to manage each of them. Class draws image and moves it in own logic.
Thus, created an array of instances, each of whom is responsible for move image.

Comment: >> Which drawRect are you overriding in your last code snippet? Is this the Behavior class?

Yes, in the Behavior class. But it's just a sample

Comment: But `b` does get added as a subview of your view controller's view at some point? Can you show the actual code you are using?

Comment: everything's working ) you can see sample of my code there: http://file.qip.ru/get/sB1Iq7UX/sample.html

Comment: Well done! Glad you got it working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to add an image view over simple UIView then just do `[self.view addSubview:imageview];` If you are getting that Image from Behaviour class method then return UIImageView from that method and the add it to your view
 Try this:

```
Behavior *b = [[Behavior alloc] init];
```

Then write one method in Behaviour class

```
-(UIImageView*) initilizeWithType:(NSString *)type position:(CGRect) pos mapArray:(NSMutableArray *) mapArr {
// Your Logic

return  imgView;  //UIImageView object
}
```

Then call this method in your viewcontroller as

```
UIImageView *imgView=[b initilizeWithType:@"YOUR STRING" position:YOUR RECT pos mapArray:YOUR ARRAY ];
```

Comment: message: "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'Behavior *'"

Comment: Make behaviour as a subclass of UIView. OR U can set the return type of the method(in Behaviour) as UIImageView OR just do `[self addSubView:imageView]`

Comment: `-(id)initilizeWithType:(NSString *)type position:(CGRect) pos mapArray:(NSMutableArray *) mapArr {
    UIImageView *imgg;
    ....
    return imgg;
}
`
doesn't work

Comment: Well, as I have already written, `[self addSubView:imageView]` doesn't work too..

Comment: Set return type as '-(UIImageView *)initilizeWithType:(NSString *)type position:(CGRect) pos mapArray:(NSMutableArray *) mapArr { UIImageView *imgg; .... return imgg; }'

Comment: yeah ) it works ) thank u a lot )

In the class Behavior has methods to move image. How can I move image now?

Comment: everything is working! ) i can move my image! ) Thank you very much! ))

Answer (score 0):

```
imgg.frame = rect;
```

This line assigns your imageView frame to... nothing as far as I can see. Should this be `pos` or `rectForDraw`? When adding to your view in drawRect you are explicitly setting a real frame so this is probably where the difference lies.

Comment: i had mistake. i wrote it for example.
Even if I write 'imgg.frame = CGRectmake(100, 100, 100, 100)', the image does not appear.